Get specific folder from subfolders list
I'm trying to get a specific folder from a subfolder list I got from FSO method
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolders = objFSO.getFolder(test).SubFolders

Basically trying to access objFolders like this doesn't work and I'm not understanding why
    objFolders(1)
    objFolders.Item(1)


Use the folder name.

Or you could use a For Each itm in ObjFolders to iterate through each one.  Doesn't explain why Item(1) doesn't work though.

What logic do you use to define the first folder? First alphabetically, first created, etc.?

@BigBen : can't use the folderName as I don't know it before iterating to it and reading it's name property
I guess it is sorted alphabetically, the format of the folders are "yyyymm" when I check the subfolders Object the folders are sorted alphabetically. I will need to access the last one from my list

@DarrenBartrup-Cook : I actually need to do something on one specific folder only I don't want to iterate through the entire list for nothing

All the MS documentation for the SubFolders/Folders "collections" use For Each to examine the results. I can't find a link to the evidence but the index on those collections is via  Key only - i.e. the folder name. I don't think there is an easy way to convert it to an array to fudge and index either.
You also need to remember that "first" will vary - there is no concept of these names appearing in any fixed order

@CHill60 ok I'm not crazy, it was impossible to do from the beginning. Thx

Reference the Alphabetically Last Subfolder
The Calling Procedure (Example)
Sub RefLastSubfolderTEST()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const ROOT_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Test"

    ' Attempt to create a reference to the last subfolder.
    Dim fsoLast As Object: Set fsoLast = RefLastSubfolder(ROOT_FOLDER_PATH)
    
    ' A message from the function has already alerted you,
    ' unless 'ShowMessages' is set to 'False'.
    If fsoLast Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' The reference was created. Continue, e.g.:
    MsgBox "Found subfolder """ & fsoLast.Name & """ located in """ _
        & ROOT_FOLDER_PATH & """.", vbInformation

End Sub

The Called Procedure (Helper Function)
Function RefLastSubfolder( _
    RootFolderPath As String, _
    Optional ShowMessages As Boolean = True) _
As Object
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Reference Last Subfolder"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Reference the root (initial) folder.
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fso.FolderExists(RootFolderPath) Then
        If ShowMessages Then
            MsgBox "The path """ & RootFolderPath & """ doesn't exist!", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim fsoCurrent As Object, fsoLast As Object, IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    ' Loop and create a reference to the first subfolder. Then for each
    ' subfolder that has a greater name, reference it instead.
    For Each fsoCurrent In fso.GetFolder(RootFolderPath).Subfolders
        If IsFirstFound Then ' all but first
            If fsoCurrent.Name > fsoLast.Name Then Set fsoLast = fsoCurrent
        Else ' first
            Set fsoLast = fsoCurrent: IsFirstFound = True
        End If
    Next fsoCurrent
    
    If Not IsFirstFound Then ' no subfolder found; exit
        If ShowMessages Then
            MsgBox "No subfolders found in """ & RootFolderPath & """!", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Asssign to the result.
    Set RefLastSubfolder = fsoLast

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    If ShowMessages Then
        MsgBox "Run-time error'" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
            & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

